# PL SQL: Connect string and number WITHOUT Concat but '+'

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way in PL SQL to write

```
Output('Variable a:' + var_a + '; Variable b: ' + var_b);
```

instead of this long silly code:

```
Output(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT("Variable a', var_a), '; Variable b'), var_b));
```

Comment: If only this was [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/apps/search/search.jsp?word=Concatenation+&product=e50529-01&book=LNPLS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PL/SQL uses the same operator as standard SQL to concatenate strings: `||`

```
Output('Variable a:' || var_a || '; Variable b: ' || var_b);
                                 ^ -- the double quotes were also wrong
```